# Save local text file detecting new lines and whitespaces of contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, dom

Say i have a contenteditable div with this text as input

```
<div id="board" contenteditable="true">
   <div>ab</div>
   <div>   cd</div>
   <div></div>
   <div>e   f</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var text = "";

if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.selectAllChildren(el);
    text = sel.toString();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
} 

else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
    var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    textRange.moveToElementText(el);
    text = textRange.text;
}
```

alerting `text` will give me the desired format (with new lines and whitespace). But  when i saved it using `filesaver.js` new lines are lost in the text files. how would i manipulate text before saving it?

Answer (score 1):

What does `text = sel.toString();` return? If you want your text to be "lineable", it must include `\r\n` at some point.

If `sel.selectAllChildren(el);` returns a collection, it must be iterated over. `text = sel.toString()` may join all the values with an empty separator e.g. "". Your separator must be `\r\n`.

The recipe is as follows:

- select all `#board's div children`
- then get the `text value` of each that you place in an array
- join the values with `yourArray.join('\r\n')`